# Case statement to validate date in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I am a newbie in Teradata. I need to check a date column has valid date in case statement. This column is in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. If this field is invalid need to use '1900-01-01' as default. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to check for it

```
select 
case when CALENDAR_DATE is null then  cast('1900-01-01'  as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            else cast(datee as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')  end valid_date
from YOUR_TABLE  XYZ
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR CAL ON (CALENDAR_DATE (FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') (CHAR(10))) = XYZ.datee;
```

And this a link where all possible solutions had been disscussed previously.
https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/to-find-invalid-dates